# how to reset time after a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I already have a start button but  what i need is to restart the button when the conditions are met and make the button clickable again.

HTML CODE:

```
 <div id="content" class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6 pull-right align-right white" style="max-width: 540px;">
    <div style="display: block;">
```

Comment: Please add HTML & CSS as well- JSFiddle would be good

Answer (score 0):

added "clicked" var to check if time have to restart

```
//---------------------------toggle-----------------------
$( ".picture" ).click(function() {
  $( "#container" ).toggle( "fold", 500 );

});
$( ".numbers1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#numbers" ).toggle();

});
//==========================================================

var done = true;
var clicked = true;
function check(counter){

         if (counter >= 0) {
           $("#count").text(counter);
         }
         if (counter === 0 && winner === 0) {
           $("<div title='Oh no!'><center><img src='https://www.foreignlanguagesforkids.com/playa/images/shark.png'></center><p style='text-align: center;'>Let's get Calamity Carl to the hospital, pronto! Lucky for Carl, the doctors are experts at fixing him up and he will be as good as new in no time, only to get himself in trouble all over again!</p><div style='margin-top: 15px; width: 100%;'><div style='float: left; width: 48%; text-align; center;'><a class='btn button' href='https://www.foreignlanguagesforkids.com/playa'>Play Again</a></div><div style='float: right; width: 48%; text-align: center;'><a class='btn button' href='https://www.foreignlanguagesforkids.com/playa'>End Game</a></div><div style='clear: both;'></div></div></div>").dialog();
           clearInterval(timer);
            $('#fail')[0].play();
            clicked = true;
         }

}
$("#startClock").click(function() {
var counter = 60;
 var winner = 0;
var winners=0;



//===============================================CAR DRAGGABLE===================

    $("#car").draggable({
    revert: "invalid", containment: "#wrapper",
    start: function(event, ui){
        if(!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        if($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length){
            setTimeout(function(){
                 $('#win').text(winner+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned');
            },500);
            winner = 1;
            clearInterval(timer);
            clicked = true;
        }
    }
    });

     $("#two").draggable({
    revert: "invalid", containment: "#wrapper",
    start: function(event, ui){
        if(!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        if($(".correct").length == $(".drop2").length){
            setTimeout(function(){
                  $('#win1').text(winners+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned');
            },500);
            winners = 2;

            clearInterval(timer);
            clicked = true;

        }
    }
    });

//===============================================/CAR DRAGGABLE     End===================

//====================================================================Two               draggable==========================

   if(counter > 59 && clicked){
   clicked = false;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
    check(counter);
    counter--;
    },1000);

}


//=========================================/TWO DRAGGABLE END==========================

});

//===================================================CAR DROPPABLE================================

$("#carDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#car",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.is("#car")){
            $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
            done = false;
            ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
            $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                done = true;
            });
        }
    }
});

//==================================================two droppable===========================

$("#twoDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#two",
    drop2: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.is("#two")){
            $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
            done = false;
            ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
            $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                done = true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i already have a button to start clock what i want is after an if statement the clock will restart to 60 secs and i can click it again

Comment: i added what i guess you need.. please explain what you are trying to do with this script

Comment: i have a button already i just didnt include it here.. That script is a draggable and droppable and you need to start the clock to be able to drag it what i want is after it is dropped  if($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length){}   then i want for the clock to reset again. i tried adding counter=60 and it works, the countdown returned to 60 but it is automatic not after i click it

Comment: Please update the code.. So you want: When ($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) if you click (WHERE?) reset the time to 60 and start it again to count down.

Comment: the if (counter === 0 && winner === 0) { is not working and i can still drag even if the start game is not clicked

Comment: Just add "clicked = true;" when you need to restart your timer.. your jsfiddle expired..

Answer (score 0):

Like Luca said it is unclear what you're asking, is it possible to elaborate more on what it is you're wanting to do?

From what I understand you just want to reset the timer, which would be the variable.

If so then that would be this:

```
if(counter == 0) {
    counter = 60;
}
```

Comment: What i want is after the the if statement inside stop: function(event, ui){} i want the timer to return to 60 seconds and it will be clickable again cuz my problem is after the if statement the time just stops and if i click the startclock button nothing happens

Comment: Your code helped it restart the time but i want it to restart after clicking the button again not automatic

Answer (score 0):

Below are things I noticed.

1. `javascript:toggle(); toggle is not defined in "startClock". Either define it or remove it
2. There is no element with id "fail". So below line throws error

   $('#fail')[0].play();
3. Remove the condition `if (!timer)` and define the variable "timer" inside "startClock" click event.

Apply the above changes and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
// setup timer, keep pointer to it in mytimer variable

var mytimer = setTimeout(function(){
   alert('hello 2s have passed!');
},2000);

// cancel timer

clearTimeout(mytimer);
```

Please note that its `setInterval()` has `clearInterval()`.